# Store default translation if key is missing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-i18n

I am trying to store a default translation if a translation is missing in Rails.
After much struggle I came up with this:

```
backend = I18n.backend
if not backend.exists?(locale, key)
  backend.store_translations(locale, {key => locale.to_s + "-" + key.to_s})
end
```

The problem is, it stores the default values but it does not find them. Any idea what is wrong here?

Comment: What code are you running to find the values after they are stored?

Comment: I am using a key-value backend and use Redis with it. The `KeyValue` backend is trying to find the values. I just use `t` to translate strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After so much headache, I found the problem:

It is because the dots in my keys are converted to their unicode character when stored, so, they are not found. For example `actions.save` is converted to `actions\u0001save`.

I don't know why this happens.